# developing software on smartphone

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, symbian, windows-mobile-6

platform can be symbian OS,windows 6.0

I want to known is there any software like (visual stdio 2008) that will be installed in my smartphone 
and i can write my code and compile it and execute it in smart phone

plz help me out

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Python](http://wiki.opensource.nokia.com/projects/Python_for_S60) on a Symbian phone, you will need to find some sort of text editor though.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should look at Maemo-based Nokia devices like Nokia N900. It runs almost native Linux with root access, so you're able to run a GNU toolchain on it.

Answer (score 1):

try theses alternatives

- [Pocket C#](http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2004/06/09/151853.aspx) from [dot GNU Project](http://dotgnu.org/)
- [C# IDE Mobile](http://www.pocketpcfreeware.com/en/index.php?soft=1989)
- [Pocket C# Combo 1.10](http://www.pocketgear.com/en/usd/3354241,product-details.html)
- [PocketGCC 1.50](http://www.pocketgear.com/en/usd/3354171,product-details,PocketGCC.html)

Comment: As far i know,all theses tools just run in windows mobile.

Comment: so it means there is no software symbain smartphone's

Answer (score 1):

Look into QT (http://qt.nokia.com) for symbian and windows 6.5 phones